# What is WEBDAV?

Tags: iphone, webdav

I want to use WebDAv server to share files among systems and (iPod or iPhone) in my iphone project. To use it, do I have to use an individual webserver? Or is it a built in facility?

Comment: you want to use something but you don't know what it is?

Comment: @Huperniketes If they are the same thing, yes. If they are different, no ;-)

Answer (score 8):

WebDAV is a way to [share files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) through a web server, which includes functionality for file locking and versioning.

Presumably, you would run [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) or another WebDAV-savvy web server, enabling access to a folder and its contents through the setting of relevant permissions.

This service would be run on a server somewhere — such as a Mac OS X workstation, which has Apache installed by default — and which has files that you want to present to the outside world.

Your iPhone device would connect to the WebDAV server through a WebDAV client; for example, [DAV-E](http://greenbytes.de/dav-e.html). The client locates and displays a list of files and folders, allowing uploads and downloads.

Answer (score 2):

It typically isn't a built-in facility, but can be enabled as an extension of existing webservers, e.g [`mod_dav`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dav.html) for Apache, [`WebDAV publishing`](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/WebDAV-IIS.html) for IIS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Short for *Web-based Distributed Authoring and Versioning*.

*WebDav* is sometimes referred to as *DAV*.

An *IETF standard* set of *platform-independent extensions* to *HTTP*

It allows users to *collaboratively edit and manage files on remote Web servers*.

It features XML properties on metadata, *locking* - which prevents authors from overwriting each other's changes - *namespace manipulation* and *remote file management*.

To know more Visit the [FAQ](http://www.webdav.org/other/faq.html)